# @XMLAnyElement in the base class and @XmlValue at subclass

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have an existing project where i have to introduce JAXB for serialization .
I have a Base class(GrandParent) from where all the classes that have to be serialized are extended . And i want to have an element in all the child classes which will store any unknown valid xml found during marshal/unmarshal. That's why I created a new class(RandomBody) which will store unknown xml and make it a protected member variable of the base class(GrandParent)  , so that all the child classes will include it by hierarchy .

So far it's OK . The problem arises when I include any `@XmlValue` attribute in any of the child classes . as a `If a class has @XmlElement property, it cannot have @XmlValue property.`

I also need to use `@XmlValue` in some of the derived classes . But as `@XmlValue is not allowed on a class that derives another class.` , I made some intermediate classes and marked them as `@XmlTransient` and then extend them to my leaf classes .

Please look at the structure below

```
public class GrandParent{
    @XmlAnyElement
    protected RandomBody randomXML;
    .............
}

public class RandomBody{
    private String anyUnknownText;
    ..............
}

@XmlTransient
public class Father extends GrandParent{

}

public class Boy extends Father{
   @XmlValue
   private String name;
   //This has automatically included the ability to handle anyUnknownText from RandomBody
   //And thus will marshal/Unmarshall any unknown node 
}
public class Girl extends Father{
   @XmlValue
   private String name;
   //This has automatically included the ability to handle anyUnknownText from RandomBody
   //And thus will marshal/Unmarshall any unknown node 
}

@XmlRootElement
public class Main{
   @XmlElement
   private Boy boy;
   @XmlElement
   private Girl girl;
   @XmlElement
   private String id;
}
```

So , my problem is clear here . I have two problem in this code snippet :

1. I cannot use `@XmlAnyElement` in the `GrandParent` , as this will conflict with my `Boy,Girl` to have `@Xmlvalue` as `If a class has @XmlElement property, it cannot have @XmlValue property.`
2. I have to declare my `GrandParent` as `@XmlTransient` to avoid conflict with `Boy,Girl` as `@XmlValue is not allowed on a class that derives another class.`

- Can anyone help me how can I include a variable at the topmost level of the hierarchy to handle all valid unknown xml for the child classes ?

  And the next question that follows is , how can i add @XmlValue like property in the child classes when I have @XmlAnyElement in the Base?

  Is my requirement really possible to handle through Jaxb ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my problem by replacing all the `@XmlValue` with `@XmlMixed` attribute.
I can now safely define `@XmlAnyElement` in the `RandomBody` of `GrandParent`